# DSolve finding suprious solutions with wrong functional dependence

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I've restated the question in a simpler form: Solving this equation in terms of g[w]

```
DSolve[w*D[m[w, r], w] + (g[w]*r^2 + r)*D[m[w, r], r] - m[w, r]*(3*g[w]*r + 1) + (g[w]*r^2 + D[g[w], w]*r^3) == 0, g[w], w]
```

gives 
$
\left\{\left\{g(w)\to c_1 \exp \left(\int_1^w \frac{r^2 \left(-m^{(0,1)}(K[1],r)\right)+3 r m(K[1],r)-r^2}{r^3} \, dK[1]\right)+\exp \left(\int_1^w \frac{r^2 \left(-m^{(0,1)}(K[1],r)\right)+3 r m(K[1],r)-r^2}{r^3} \, dK[1]\right) \int_1^w \frac{-r m^{(0,1)}(K[2],r)-K[2] m^{(1,0)}(K[2],r)+m(K[2],r)}{r^3 \exp \left(\int_1^{K[2]} \frac{r^2 \left(-m^{(0,1)}(K[1],r)\right)+3 r m(K[1],r)-r^2}{r^3} \, dK[1]\right)} \, dK[2]\right\}\right\}
$

This is now a function of g[w,r] because Mathematica seems to be just solving this with an integrating factor.

How can I make Mathematica do something smarter, or what are good strategies for satisfying this functional dependence (rather than guessing m)?

The above equation can also be solved for m[w,r] and in this case g[w] can be imposed, but this is not really ideal because m is physically determined.

Comment: Capital `C` is a built-in symbol in `Mathematica`, you mustn't use it as an unknown  function in `DSolve`.

Comment: Apart from using a reserved symbol, `C[1]`, there are five variables, {A, B, C[1], \[Alpha], m}, and only four equations.

Comment: My typing C_1[w] here was just for presentation, but Mathematica actually gives the same answer even if it's replaced with something else like F[w].

Comment: There aren't 5 variables - if the conformal killing equation is contracted with the metric this gives $\alpha = \frac{2}{d} \nabla_\rho \chi^\rho$. Then by using the ansatz $\chi = (A, r B/2,0 ,0)$ this simplifies so that the $(\theta \theta)$ equation just gives $B=\alpha$. 

In solving the system of equations, one gets from the $(rr)$ equation that $A[w,r]=A[w]$ and from $(wr)$ that $B=\partial_w A[w] + r C[1][w]$. So the system is actually over determined and there are only 3 variables, A[w], C[1][w] and m[w,r].